# Hitting break in an ASP.Net project produces dialog "Unable to break execution. This process is not currently

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

When you hit break in an ASP.Net project it pops up a dialog saying "Unable to break execution. This process is not currently executing the type of code that you selected to debug." and no breakpoints are hit either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Project, Properties, Web, Debuggers, tick ASP.Net.